# How to increase query execution time? Django putty

Tags: mysql, django, database, server

I get an error **504 gateway time-out** when my user tries to get some data from the database, the query that is to be executed to fetch the data is very complex and takes some time to be executed, so I want to increase the query execution time in my server so user can get the data, so how can I do this from my **putty** the application is written in **Django**

Comment: Putty is simply an SSH client - it has nothing to do with how your server is set up. Timeouts are generally configured on your wsgi server (w.g., uwsgi, gunicorn) - so you need to find out how Django is set up to run, and edit the configuration of your wsgi server to increase the timeout. It's not possible to say how without knowing how your system is configured.

Comment: Thanks @solarissmoke the application is configured in gunicorn WSGI server